# Webpage where the Google Analytics code is firing two pageviews requests

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, pageviews

I have a webpage where the Analytics code is firing two pageview request, but it has the code just once.

The website is: https://portaldeassinaturas.com.br/

And my code is:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) { i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () { (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments) }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src=g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m) })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga'); ga('create', 'UA-32691304-1', 'auto', { 'allowLinker': true }); ga('require', 'linker'); ga('linker:autoLink', ['portaldeassinaturas.com.br', 'assinaseg.com.br', 'assinebrasil.com.br', 'assinadornotarial.com.br']); ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Any idea why is happening this?

Answer (score 0):

The code is fired from two locations:

1) https://portaldeassinaturas.com.br/bundles/master?v=I73D1-ZwT-a5pvx_S_uGpNRy4A9hOZMSotVOs5fmapk1

2) https://portaldeassinaturas.com.br/bundles/angulartics?v=cDEKTekPjCER_whdGr74UesZjZCv_PYRW8JWN0RbObc1

resulting in two pageviews records